# Travis CI fails to compile Pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, continuous-integration, cocoapods, travis-ci

I'm trying to set up Travis CI for my iOS project.

Here is my travis yml file

```
language: objective-c

env:
  matrix:
    - export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

script:
  - xctool -workspace TravisExample.xcworkspace -scheme TravisExample -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
  - xctool test -workspace TravisExample.xcworkspace -scheme TravisExampleTests -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO

cache:
  - bundler
  - cocoapods
```

Travis failed with errors like this

Support Files/Bolts/Bolts-prefix.pch' file not found
Support Files/AFNetworking/AFNetworking-prefix.pch' file not found

I have AFNetworking and Bolts as dependencies in my project managed by cocoapods.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: I hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this lines before script:

```
before_install:
    - rvm use system
    - sudo gem install cocoapods -v '0.39.0'
```

It looks like some Travis Machines are using old Cocoapods versions. With this lines you force Travis to use the version you want.

Check which version are you using in your machine with this line in your Terminal:

```
pod --version
```

[I wrote a blog post about Travis-CI, maybe it can help you.](https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/05/add-travis-ci-to-your-coding-challenge/)